# Need help in understanding code output please

Tags: python

I am learning python from online channels and I came across a question in Instagram. I need help in understanding why the output of the below code is 111111 as '1' is a string and 2 and 3 are ints. any help is appreciated. Thanks.

code - `print('1'*2*3)`

Output - `111111`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` between a string and an `int` repeats the string that number of times. So `'1'*2` repeat the string `'1'` twice, producing `'11'`. Then you evaluate `'11' * 3` and repeat `'11'` thrice, producing the end result of `'111111'`.

Answer (score 1):

The code: `print('1'*2*3)` is the same as: `print('1' * 6)` which means *repeat the string '1' six times as a single string.*